# Get all vertices having a labelname

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-graph

I am using ibm graph in bluemix and new to this.

I created a graph named 'test' using the GUI provided by bluemix and uploaded the sample data 'Music Festival' provided by ibm in that graph.

Now I am trying to query all the vertices having label 'attendee' using below query.

`def gt = graph.traversal();
gt.V().hasLabel("attendee");`

But I am getting error as

`Error: Error encountered evaluating script def gt = graph.traversal();gt.V().hasLabel("attendee"); with reason com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanException: Could not find a suitable index to answer graph query and graph scans are disabled: [(~label = attendee)]:VERTEX`

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Can somebody tell where am i going wrong?

How can i get rid of this error and get the expected output?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

@Radhika, Your Gremlin query is a valid Gremlin query. However, some vendors (such as IBM Graph and Titan) chose to only allow users to start their queries with a query that is indexed.This is to make sure you get the performance of your queries. Calling `hasLabel()` by itself will give you the `Could not find a suitable index...` error as you can't create indexes for labels. What you need to do is follow this step with a step that uses a indexed property as in this query :

```
graph.traversal();gt.V().hasLabel("band").has("genre","pop");
```

An index for `genre` has been created in the schema for the sample music festival data as you can see below

```
{
  "propertyKeys": [
   { "name": "name", "dataType": "String", "cardinality": "SINGLE" },
   { "name": "gender", "dataType": "String", "cardinality": "SINGLE" },
   { "name": "age", "dataType": "Integer", "cardinality": "SINGLE" },
   { "name": "genre", "dataType": "String", "cardinality": "SINGLE" },
   { "name": "monthly_listeners", "dataType": "String", "cardinality": "SINGLE" },
   { "name":"date","dataType":"String","cardinality":"SINGLE" },
   { "name":"time","dataType":"String","cardinality":"SINGLE" }
  ],
  "vertexLabels": [
   { "name": "attendee" },
   { "name": "band" },
   { "name": "venue" }
  ],
  "edgeLabels": [
   { "name": "bought_ticket", "multiplicity": "MULTI" },
   { "name":"advertised_to","multiplicity":"MULTI" },
   { "name":"performing_at","multiplicity":"MULTI" }
  ],
  "vertexIndexes": [
   { "name": "vByName", "propertyKeys": ["name"], "composite": true, "unique": false },
   { "name": "vByGender", "propertyKeys": ["gender"], "composite": true, "unique": false },
   { "name": "vByGenre", "propertyKeys": ["genre"], "composite": true, "unique": false}
  ],
  "edgeIndexes" :[
    { "name": "eByBoughtTicket", "propertyKeys": ["time"], "composite": true, "unique": false }
  ]
```

That's why the above query works and you need to do the same.

1. If you don't have a schema, create one. You can model it after the
   one above or follow the [API
   doc](https://ibm-graph-docs.ng.bluemix.net/api.html#schema-apis)
2. Create an (Vertex/Label) index for the properties that you'll start
   your traversals from. In this example, `Name, Gender and Genre` for
   vertex properties and `name` for the edge properties.
3. Call the [schema
   endpoint](https://ibm-graph-docs.ng.bluemix.net/api.html#schema-apis)
   to add your schema to your graph
4. It's recommended to create your schema before adding any data to
   your graph so that you don't have to reindex later. That'll save you
   a lot of time.
5. Once you create your schema, you can't modify what you created
   already, but you can add new properties/indexes later on.

Look at the following code samples for [Java and Nodejs](https://ibm-graph-docs.ng.bluemix.net/examples.html#node.js) for the exact code to use.

I hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Alaa. I spent my complete day finding what is wrong with the query to find out even though its valid it will not work... Thats disappointing

Comment: @Radhika, sorry to hear that. Please feel free to post your issues on SO when you see and we'll answer you right away. Also feel free to join our slack channel and our dev team will gladly help you there as well http://ibm-graph-slackinvite.mybluemix.net/